# Heartbeat - user delete comment from node -> delete also from heartbeat stream

Tags: 7, nodes, comments, heartbeat

I'm using Heartbeat to show activity on the site. When user post comment to the node Heartbeat activity stream shows that comment. But when user delete comment it does not delete it from the Heartbeat activity stream.

How to delete comment also from Heartbeat activity stream? This should be done of course automatically when user delete comment from the node.

Same thing for deleting nodes.

In the Rules there was no Heartbeat log delete possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heartbeat module implemented `hook_user_delete()` and `hook_node_delete()` hooks itself. take a look at their implementations.. I think you can implement `hook_comment_delete($comment)` hook in your module to delete activities from `heartbeat_activity` table. Here is the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_delete/7).